# SQL Transpose rows to columns (group by key variable) NOT using pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

The following code is close to doing what I need EXCEPT I should generate columns (p1,p2,p3...) dynamically  AND I can't use pivot (see [SQL Transpose rows to columns (group by key variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457054/sql-transpose-rows-to-columns-group-by-key-variable)).

What I am using now in SQL Server 2008:

```
Select InvoiceNum, 
Max(Case when seq =0  Then product_Description end) as p1,
Max(Case when seq =1 Then product_Description end) as p2

 From  

( Select InvoiceNum, Product_Description,

    Row_Number() Over(Partition by InvoiceNum
        Order by InvoiceNum) - 1 seq

From #tmpTable
)d
 Group by InvoiceNum
```

Thank you StackOverFlow Community!!

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic sql. The question you link to includes an example of how to do this.  Oh, and you can use PIVOT for this.

Comment: I get 'Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.'

Comment: I don't have permissions to do this.

Comment: Have you tried writing any dynamic sql like the example in the link?

Comment: You can do this as a crosstab. I prefer that to PIVOT anyway. It is slightly faster, easier to read imho and works even with a legacy compatibility level. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/ http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: What is the current compatibility level of your SQL 2008 server?

Answer (score 1):

I think, like the comments also say, you should use Dynamic SQL with a PIVOT table. It can probably be done more efficiently than this.

Create the table and put some data in it:

```
create table invoiceTable (
    InvoiceNum int,
    Product_Description nvarchar(20)
)

insert into invoiceTable values (1, 'inv1 row 1'),(1, 'inv1 row 2'),(1, 'inv1 row 3'),(2, 'inv2 row 1'),(2, 'inv2 row 2')
```

declare the necessary variables

```
declare @maxNo int
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @i int = 0
```

find the max row number:

```
select @maxNo = max(seq) from 
    (
    Select 
         InvoiceNum
        ,Product_Description
        ,Row_Number() Over(Partition by InvoiceNum Order by InvoiceNum) - 1 seq
    From 
        invoiceTable
    ) maxRowNo
```

Build the dynamic query

```
set @query = 
'
Select 
    *
From  
( 
    Select 
         InvoiceNum
        ,Product_Description
        ,Row_Number() Over(Partition by InvoiceNum Order by InvoiceNum) - 1 seq
    From 
        invoiceTable
) d
pivot
(
    min(Product_Description)
    for seq in (
    '

while (@i <= @maxNo)
begin
    if (@i > 0) set @Query += ','
    set @query += '['+CAST(@i as nvarchar)+']'

    set @i += 1;
end

set @query +=
    ')
) pvt
'
```

Execute the query

```
exec sp_executesql @query
```

This gives the following resultset:

```
InvoiceNum  0           1           2
1           inv1 row 1  inv1 row 2  inv1 row 3
2           inv2 row 1  inv2 row 2  NULL
```