# Oracle SQL - Transpose Column to Row Grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, grouping, transpose

I have the following SQL query running against an Oracle 11g instance that works great:

```
SELECT
    TRIM(PART_NM) || TRIM(PART_NO),
    TRIM(MKBY_IND),
    MFG_TYP

FROM
    TblPARTS

WHERE
    ORDER_START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 365)
    AND
    TO_CHAR(TRIM(PART_NO)) != '99'
```

Which yields results like the following:

```
| Part | Make / Buy |    Area   |
|:----:|:----------:|:---------:|
| AU54 |      M     |    Demo   |
| ZA45 |      M     | Construct |
| AD28 |      B     | Construct |
| SX73 |      B     | Construct |
| MO47 |      M     | Construct |
| IN66 |      B     | Construct |
| RP42 |      M     |    Demo   |
| HF77 |      B     |    Demo   |
| IE43 |      B     |  Personal |
| OX11 |      B     |  Personal |
| ZE45 |      M     |    Demo   |
| JH21 |      M     | Construct |
| AM91 |      M     | Construct |
| DS50 |      M     |    Demo   |
| LE29 |      M     |    Demo   |
| IP91 |      M     |    Demo   |
| ID42 |      M     |    Demo   |
| RI96 |      M     |    Demo   |
```

I have no problems there. However, it has been requested for me to transpose the Area column and instead group the rows by it. Something akin to:

```
|    Part   | Make / Buy |
|:---------:|:----------:|
| CONSTRUCT |  CONSTRUCT |
|    AU54   |      M     |
|    ZA45   |      M     |
|    AD28   |      B     |
|    SX73   |      M     |
|    MO47   |      M     |
|    IN66   |      B     |
|    JH21   |      M     |
|    AM91   |      B     |
|    DEMO   |    DEMO    |
|    RP42   |      M     |
|    HF77   |      M     |
|    ZE45   |      M     |
|    DS50   |      B     |
|    LE29   |      M     |
|    IP91   |      M     |
|    ID42   |      M     |
|    RI96   |      M     |
|  PERSONAL |  PERSONAL  |
|    IE43   |      M     |
|    OX11   |      M     |
```

In short, I am looking to find the unique values in the "Area" column (`MFG_TYP`) field, and to be able to group by them in a row. It should be noted that the three entries listed are valid in my dataset, but are subject to change, so I am not looking for a static solution, but instead a way to dynamically apply the transformation across all unique values in the `Area` column.

I have tried looking at these resource's but **currently do not** understand how to build a solution. Any advice is appreciated.

- [SQL Transpose rows to columns (group by key variable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457054/sql-transpose-rows-to-columns-group-by-key-variable)
- [Transpose / Pivot distinct row attribute as column and group another attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188158/transpose-pivot-distinct-row-attribute-as-column-and-group-another-attribute?lq=1)
- https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/

Comment: Please provide your sample data that would be helpful

Comment: The sample data is included in the post. What needs to be edited? @Avi

Comment: I just see the results you are getting from the query and your expected result.

Comment: Yes. Does that not qualify as sample data? @Avi. I can do a `SELECT *` from the table but I don't know how beneficial that would be. I am happy to provide you whtever you need to help, but in the past I have also been told to use what I have currently have and then my expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution with [ROLLUP Extension to GROUP BY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/aggreg.htm#i1007413):

```
with
  TblPARTS(Part, Make_Buy, Area) as (
    select 'AU54', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'ZA45', 'M', 'Construct' from dual union all
    select 'AD28', 'B', 'Construct' from dual union all
    select 'SX73', 'B', 'Construct' from dual union all
    select 'MO47', 'M', 'Construct' from dual union all
    select 'IN66', 'B', 'Construct' from dual union all
    select 'RP42', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'HF77', 'B', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'IE43', 'B', 'Personal' from dual union all
    select 'OX11', 'B', 'Personal' from dual union all
    select 'ZE45', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'JH21', 'M', 'Construct' from dual union all
    select 'AM91', 'M', 'Construct' from dual union all
    select 'DS50', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'LE29', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'IP91', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'ID42', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'RI96', 'M', 'Demo' from dual union all
    select 'AO42', 'M', 'Public' from dual union all
    select 'OA42', 'B', 'Public' from dual
  ),
  a as (
    select
      Part, Make_Buy, Area,
      GROUPING_ID(Area, Part, Make_Buy) gid
    from TblPARTS
    group by rollup(Area, (Part, Make_Buy))
    having GROUPING_ID(Area, Part, Make_Buy) < 7
  )
select
  coalesce(Part, Area) Part,
  coalesce(Make_Buy, Area) Make_Buy
from a
order by Area, gid desc
```

**Output:**

```
+------------+-----------+
|    PART    |  MAKE_BUY |
+------------+-----------+
| Construct  | Construct |
| AM91       | M         |
| IN66       | B         |
| JH21       | M         |
| SX73       | B         |
| ZA45       | M         |
| AD28       | B         |
| MO47       | M         |
| Demo       | Demo      |
| ZE45       | M         |
| RP42       | M         |
| RI96       | M         |
| LE29       | M         |
| IP91       | M         |
| ID42       | M         |
| HF77       | B         |
| AU54       | M         |
| DS50       | M         |
| Personal   | Personal  |
| OX11       | B         |
| IE43       | B         |
| Public     | Public    |
| OA42       | B         |
| AO42       | M         |
+------------+-----------+
```

Test it online with [Rextester](https://rextester.com/YNDX61505).

Comment: Can you explain the `< 7`, what would that be for?

Comment: @JerryM., `7` is the decimal representation of the bit vector `111`, which corresponds to a superaggregate row in which values of the columns `Area`, `Part` and `Make_Buy` are `NULL`. Look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions072.htm#SQLRF00648.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    'CONSTRUCT' AS "Part",
    'CONSTRUCT' AS "Make / Buy"
FROM DUAL

UNION

SELECT
    TRIM(PART_NM) || TRIM(PART_NO) AS "Part",
    TRIM(MKBY_IND) AS "Make / Buy"
FROM
    TblPARTS
WHERE
    ORDER_START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 365)
    AND    TO_CHAR(TRIM(PART_NO)) != '99'
    AND    MFG_TYP = 'Construct'

UNION

SELECT
    'DEMO' AS "Part",
    'DEMO' AS "Make / Buy"
FROM DUAL

UNION

SELECT
    TRIM(PART_NM) || TRIM(PART_NO) AS "Part",
    TRIM(MKBY_IND) AS "Make / Buy"
FROM
    TblPARTS
WHERE
    ORDER_START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 365)
    AND    TO_CHAR(TRIM(PART_NO)) != '99'
    AND    MFG_TYP = 'Demo'

UNION

SELECT
    'PERSONAL ' AS "Part",
    'PERSONAL ' AS "Make / Buy"
FROM DUAL

UNION

SELECT
    TRIM(PART_NM) || TRIM(PART_NO)) AS "Part",
    TRIM(MKBY_IND) AS "Make / Buy"
FROM
    TblPARTS
WHERE
    ORDER_START_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 365)
    AND    TO_CHAR(TRIM(PART_NO)) != '99'
    AND    MFG_TYP = 'Personal'
```

Comment: How could this work if there are more than just those three `MFG_TYP` fields? Meaning, that number is dynamic. How can it be possible for me to adjust these to not be statically just for those three and instead do this for all unique values in the column?